# Start-ThreadJob is not detecting my variables I pass to it

Tags: multithreading, powershell, variables, jobs

I am using the command "Start-ThreadJob" to run about 600 lines. I am trying to pass 21 variables to it but when it goes to use the variables, it appears it doesn't have access to them. I tried writing them to a txt file from the job which confirmed this.

`Start-ThreadJob -InputObject ($Variable1, $Variable2, $Variable3, $Variable4, $Variable5, $Variable6, $Variable7, $Variable8, $Variable9, $Variable10,` 
Variable11, $Variable12, $Variable13, $Variable14, $Variable15, $Variable17, $Variable18, $Variable19, $Variable20, $Variable21) -ScriptBlock {
code
code
code
}`

I also tried the argument list parameter.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Argument list is an array.  Put parameters in following : `@(p1, p2, p3, .....)`.  You are missing the `@` before the parenthesis.

Comment: @jdweng, `(p1, p2, p3, ...)` is a perfectly valid array, as is `p1, p2, p3, ...`. (As an aside: `(..., ...)` is always parsed in _expression mode_, whereas `..., ...` (as a command argument) is parsed in _argument mode_ - see the conceptual [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) help topic).

Answer (score 1):

[`-InputObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7.3#-inputobject) only works with the [automatic variable `$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input):

```
$foo, $bar, $baz = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
Start-ThreadJob -InputObject ($foo, $bar, $baz) -ScriptBlock {
    $input
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Ideally you should either use the [`using:` scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.3#scope-modifiers) to reference local variables in your thread scope:

```
$foo, $bar, $baz = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock {
    $using:foo, $using:bar, $using:baz
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Or use [`-ArgumentList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7.3#-argumentlist):

```
$foo, $bar, $baz = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
Start-ThreadJob -ArgumentList $foo, $bar, $baz -ScriptBlock {
    param($foo, $bar, $baz)

    $foo, $bar, $baz
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```